# Eclipse commit comment

Tags: eclipse, svn

How can I add textbox in commit comment user form?
We use eclipse with SVN, and Tigris Subclipse.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Put the ticket number in the commit message, like:

> JIRA-123: this is the message